# Subclassing an abstract class with an unknown variable type

Tags: java, oop, generics

I'm creating a reusable property class that I want to base on an abstract class that I will subclass with different variable types in Java.

```
public abstract class Property{
protected String name;
protected <type> type;
```

/*
Here is where the problem is, The abstract class won't know what the object type is -- So that if I derive a class of StringProperty whose type is String, how do I implement my setters and getters?  in the parent class?*/

```
public void setName(String n){
  name= n;
}
public String getName(){
 return name;
}
```

}//end class

```
public class StringProperty  extends Property{
super.setName("email");
super.setType("String");


}//end class
```

I want to genericize the abstract parent so it can be derived as StringProperty, IntProperty, BoolProperty, etc.  and set the derived type at compile time, but I can't figure it out.

I want each Property Instance to have  three properties: Name, type, and Value.
inherited by the child classes? The getter method needs to know the type beforehand

Answer (score 4):

you mean generic type ?

```java
public abstract class Property<T> {
  protected String name;
  protected T type;

  public T getType() {
   return type;
  }
  public void setType(T type) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}

public class StringProperty extends Property<String> {
 ...
}
```

Comment: I would remove T type, getType, and setType.

Comment: It’s just the `name` and `type` should be private

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use constructor in your subclasses instead of setter like in StrinProperty.
2. I don't understand why you need the type variable. So use your asked value variable. Because it's a bit obvious that a StringProperty handles strings and has a String value.

   ```
   public abstract class Property<T> {
       private String name;
       private T value;

       protected Property(String name, T value) {
           this.name = name;
           this.value = value;
       }

       public String getName() {
           return name;
       }

       public void setName(String name) {
           this.name = name;
       }

       public T getValue() {
           return value;
       }

       public void setValue(T value) {
           this.value = value;
       }
   }

   public class StringProperty extends Property<String> {

       public StringProperty(String name, String value) {
           super(name, value);
       }
   }
   ```